# Multiple .innerHTML on nested conditions

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a script that lets user to select a day so it returns if they have to go to work or not according to the day. I also added a "select a day" default option so user must actually choose a day. I tried a couple of approaches and it is not working (i.e. it's not showing whatever I put into the document.getElementById("res03E09").innerHTML element)

I started in this course a couple of weeks ago so I'm pretty much lost atm.

```js
btnE09.onclick = function ejercicio09() {
  let day = document.getElementById("diaE09").value;
  //let temp = Number(document.getElementById("tempE09").value);

  if (day == "xx") {
    document.getElementById("res01E09").innerHTML = "Please select a day";
  } else if (day == "su") { //sunday, their day off
    document.getElementById("res01E09").innerHTML = "Get up";
    document.getElementById("res03E09").innerHTML = "Day off";
  } else { //hopefully the rest of days
    document.getElementById("res01E09").innerHTML = "Get up"; //the get up text must be shown on all cases
    document.getElementById("res03E09").innerHTML = "Go to work";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Ejercicio 9:</h1>
  <p>Este programa le indicará si debe salir y cómo, dados el día de la semana y la temperatura.</p>
  <label for="diaE09">¿Qué día es hoy?</label>
  <select id="diaE09">
    <option value="xx">Seleccione un día</option>
    <option value="mo">Lunes</option>
    <option value="tu">Martes</option>
    <option value="we">Miércoles</option>
    <option value="th">Jueves</option>
    <option value="fr">Viernes</option>
    <option value="sa">Sábado</option>
    <option value="su">Domingo</option>
  </select><br>
  <label for="tempE09">Temperatura (°C):</label>
  <input type="text" id="tempE09">
  <input type="button" value="Consultar" id="btnE09">
  <p id="res01E09"></p><br>
  <p id="res02E09"></p><br>
  <p id="res03E09"></p><br>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet you have shown lacks context. We can’t even tell if this is part of an event handler callback somehow, or what else is actually going on. Please provide a _proper_ [mre] of the issue.

Comment: sorry, it should be visible now.

Comment: @RubénRojas First, no need for apologies. You are unaware and hence you added a question. Its something that happens to all of us. Second, when you say its not working, please elaborate it. What are the steps to reproduce and expected output

Comment: It's showing up, you just have to scroll down because you've got the text in `p`s followed by `br`s, which puts a lot of white space between each placeholder.

Comment: please make it understandable

Comment: @RubénRojas Your code works as shown in snippet but I'm using Chrome. What browser are you using? Are you getting any error in console?